# How packets know which device on another lan to go to

Tags: router, ipv4

If I know the public IP address of a network, I can talk to the router for that network.. But how would I specify to the router which device in the network I want to start talking to? What I'm asking is pretty much this: How does a router know which device to send a received packet to, if the sending device hasn't setup a connection with the receiving device..

I understand that in the IP header of a packet resides the destination address, that is the public IP address. And when this packet is sent, it arrives at different networking devices on its journey, asking each if they contain the destination address, and if not the packet hops to another device until it finds the destination address. Once it reaches the device with the public IP address, it is forwarded to the router. Say this packet was meant for 192.168.0.7 on a device behind that router and say a connection hasn't been established prior to sending this packet, how does the router know to send the packet to 192.168.0.7? How and at which point is this specified?

Comment: Start here, [Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing)

Answer (score 4):

During the construction of a packet, your computer must first resolve any hostname used (eg, google.com) using the [Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). Your computer will then have the destination IP address and you know know where to send the packet to, but do not know the route.

In order to determine this information, Every router maintains routing tables and one or more protocols are then used in order to determine the path of the packet. Typically, for small offices and homes, the protocol used is [RIPv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol). For the most simple setups, there is only one route - the [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) which will route traffic through the [default gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) of your firewall/router. At this point, you then reach an  ISP router/cable modem. These will typically forward you via similar methods to a large router which use the [BGP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol). This is a much more complicated routing method in which large tables of routes are maintained which direct large public subnets assigned by companies like [ARIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Registry_for_Internet_Numbers) to designated routers. In the BGP protocol, these routes are updated by peers and expire and are refreshed periodically. For routing in between small and large scales (eg, within a large office or campus or an ISP, alternate protocols such as [EIGRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Interior_Gateway_Routing_Protocol) or [OSPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First) may be used

When the packet leaves your router, the source address is changed to be your router's public IP address. Thus when the packet reaches it's destination, the receiving server simply responds back to your router's address. It is then up to your router to track and maintain [stateful connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) - that is which source IPaddress:port and destination IPaddress:port combinations were communicating with each other. The creation, lifespan and teardown of these connections are maintained by your router based on it's firewall rules, [NAT policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and other firewall settings.

On a lower level, network devices maintain ARP tables of which IP addresses should be sent to which MAC address connected to the device which maintains the table. So for example, with a home router, it knows to send the packet to the MAC address of your workstation or laptop and for all other traffic, it knows to send the packet to your cable modem or ISP router. To look up an address that has never before been seen, an [ARP probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#ARP_probe) is broadcast and used to populate the table. This only tells each device it's next hop and ARP has no visibility to the next device (typically). (Eg, your workstation, will not know the MAC address of your Cable Modem/ISP Router. Only your router/WAP would.

Comment: Okay so what if I wanted to telnet to a device in a different network that my router or machine has never encountered before, how would that connection be initiated? My packets know how to get to the router providing I know the public IP, but say I wanted to telnet to 192.168.0.7 in a different network, how would the router at the dest know that my packets are meant for 192.168.0.7, considering that 1) my device or router has never encountered the receiving device or their router and 2) multiple devices in the receiving network have an open telnet port..

Comment: In this case, 192.168.0.0/16 is a reserved subnet for [private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) so this will never be a public IP address. In that case, only RIPv2 would (typically) be used. Under this protocol, you would need to create a [static route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_route) with the other router as the gateway address for the 192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.0.0/16 subnet (whichever you are using). Likewise, the other router would need a matching static route for the return traffic for your subnet and your router as the gateway address.

Comment: If you do not create a static route, this traffic will be unroutable and lost in the ether.

Comment: I know that they addresses are reserved, but my question is when my data reaches their router via the public ip address, how does the router know that I want to telnet to 192.168.0.7 in its network?

Comment: Ah, right. That's the [NAT policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)/firewall rule bit. You have to define those explicitly. Typically, you would do Port Address Translation (PAT; a NAT subtype) which is an explicitly defined policy to forward traffic for the public IP on port 23 (the telnet port) to the 192.168.0.7 address.

Comment: So is it the public IP address that is put in the IP header as the destination address? I still don't understand how the router knows that the telnet traffic is meant for 192.168.0.7 considering 192.168.0.7 isn't expecting any telnet traffic so the sending device doesn't know how to reach 192.168.0.7 @James Shewey

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The router IS expecting telnet traffic, but for the public IP address. Not the internal IP. It knows to forward it to the internal IP based on the NAT policy defined in the firewall. Responses from 192.168.0.7 get converted back to be coming from the public IP of the fireawall when the response is sent back to the original client.

Comment: I understand that the router forwards the traffic on port 23 (telnet port) to 192.168.0.7, but how does the router know that the traffic is for that host? What is included in the NAT policy that allows the router to figure out that the traffic is intended for 192.168.0.7? Sorry for dragging this on, I just really prefer to be absolutely clear on things @James Shewey

Comment: A NAT policy specifies that that traffic is for that host. An example from a Cisco ASA is: nat (outside, inside) static192.168.0.7 service tcp 23. The public IP is implicit because it is defined as the IP for the outside interface. The inside interface would be something like 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.254

Comment: So how does the NAT policy know which host traffic is for? I'm struggling here! I get the basics - data sent through router/firewall where nat is performed converting it to public ip, then sent through isp/internet to another public ip then router then internal ip.. Just not getting how the router knows which host a packet is for considering only the public ip is contained within the packet.. How does the NAT policy know which host should receive the traffic? @James Shewey

Comment: Because it is defined in the rule - "the static192.168.0.7" bit. You may find [this series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkHsKoi6eZnzJl1qTzmvBwTxrSJW4D2Jj) helpful. Especially lecture 4-10. You must remember that it is not just the IP address contained in the packet, but also the port. So I can have port 23 forwarded to 192.168.0.7 based on my NAT policies and port 80 go to 192.168.0.8 based on those same NAT policies. That would looke like: "nat (outside, inside) static192.168.0.8 service tcp 80"

Comment: I'll definitely look into that series, thanks! So is there anything in the packet that states it is destined for 192.168.0.7? Say there are 4 other devices on the dest network and the telnet port is open so any device can be connected to, how would I specify that I wanted to connect to the .0.7 device? As there have been no previous communications with the receiving device, how does the router know that the traffic shouldn't be routed to address ending .0.6? If you feel you have answered to the best of your ability and don't want to repeat yourself it's okay I'll figure it out eventually!

Comment: No, the packet doesn't contain the private address. Only the router's configuration does. And it can only forward incoming traffic to port 23 to one internal address (.0.7 in this example). You cannot forward the same external port twice. Yes, NAT sucks.